# Understanding the difference between these two decorators

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, decorator, python-decorators

New to Python and trying to understand the difference between these two decorators wherein decorator A takes as its argument the function it decorates and decorator B seems to pass the decorated function to a function inside of itself.

Decorator A:

```
def my_decorator(some_function):

  def wrapper():

      print "Something is happening before some_function() is called."

      some_function()

      print "Something is happening after some_function() is called."

  return wrapper

@ my_decorator
def just_some_function():
  print "Wheee!"
```

Will produce:

```
Something is happening before some_function() is called.
Wheee!
Something is happening after some_function() is called.
None
```

Decorator B:

```
def decorator_factory(enter_message, exit_message):

    def simple_decorator(f):
        def wrapper():
            print enter_message
            f()
            print exit_message
        return wrapper
    return simple_decorator

@decorator_factory("Start", "End")
def hello():
    print "Hello World"
```

Will produce:

```
Start
Hello World
End
None
```

I understand how it is that with Decorator A, `some_function()` can be passed to `def wrapper()` because `my_decorator()` takes `some_function` as its argument.

But with Decorator B, how is it that `simple_decorator(f)` receives the value returned by `def hello()` (as `f`) when `decorator_factory()` is taking `"start"` and `"End"` as its arguments and not `def hello()`? How does Python "know" to seemingly, automatically pass `def hello()` to `simple_decorator()`?

Comment: `@decorator_factory(...)` is a function call. The result of that function call is then applied to the decorated function ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@decorator
def foo():
    ...
```

Is just syntactic sugar for

```
def foo():
    ...

foo = decorator(foo)
```

Therefore

```
@decorator_factory(...)
def hello():
    ...
```

is equivalent to

```
def hello():
    ...

hello = decorator_factory(...)(hello)
```

which of course is equivalent to

```
def hello():
    ...

decorator = decorator_factory(...)
hello = decorator(hello)
```

Comment: So in Python, it's possible to have to two parameters, passing two separate arguments to a function a la `hello = decorator_factory(...)(hello)` ?

Comment: @Malvin9000 these are not 2 separate sets of arguments to the same function but to 2 different functions: the first set `(...)` is passed to `decorator_factory` which returns a function that takes `(hello)` as its argument.

Comment: @Malvin9000: By way of analogy, let's pretend that decorators are like hats. Functions wear hats. `decorator` is a hat that you put on a function. `decorator_factory` on the other hand, is a function that makes hats. The *return value* of that function is a hat that you can place on a function.

Comment: @JoelCornett Okay, so the return value of `decorator_factory()` (which is returning/calling the inner function `simpler_decorator()`) is the actual decorator for `hello()`?

Answer (score 2):

A decorator is an equivalent of wrapping the function it decorates.

Your example

```
@decorator_factory("Start", "End")
def hello():
    print "Hello World"

hello()
```

is the same as

```
def hello():
    print "Hello World"

hello = decorator_factory("Start", "End")(hello)

hello()
```

Comment: It's possible in Python to essentially pass two sets of arguments to one function with this: `decorator_factory("Start", "End")(hello())` ?

Comment: @Malvin9000 these are not 2 separate sets of arguments to the same function but to 2 different functions: the first set `("Start", "End")` is passed to `decorator_factory` which returns a function that takes `(hello)` as its argument.

Answer (score 1):

## Decorator A

```
@ my_decorator
def just_some_function():
```

equals:

```
just_some_function = my_decorator(just_some_function)
```

## Decorator B

```
@decorator_factory("Start", "End")
def hello():
```

equals

```
hello = decorator_factory("Start", "End")(hello)
```

because it is called once before being used, it's one step deeper

Comment: It should be `def just_some_function() .... just_some_function = my_decorator(just_some_function)`

Answer (score 0):

So no one answers properly your question: you want to know how in decorator B `simple_decorator` gets the function `f` that's because `decorator_factory` return that `simple_decorator` function so: `decorator_factory("Start", "End")(hello)` is in fact equivalent to `simple_decorator(hello)` (hello is your `f`)

P.S. You can find the answer to your questions about 2 sets of arguments in the comments.